# Get text outside of elements

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using Simple html dom to scrape a website.  The problem I have run into is that there is text positioned *outside* of any specific element.   The only element it seems to be inside is `<div id="content">`.

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="image-wrap"></div>
    <div class="gallery-container"></div>
    <h3 class="name">Here is the Heading</h3>

    All the text I want is located here !!!

    <p> </p>
    <div class="snapshot"></div>
</div>
```

I guess the webmaster has messed up and the text should actually be inside the `<p>` tags.

I've tried using this code below, however it just won't retrieve the text:

```
    $t = $scrape->find("div#content text",0);
    if ($t != null){
        $text = trim($t->plaintext);
    }
```

I'm still a newbie and still learning.   Can anyone help at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there... Use a test loop to display the content of your nodes and locate the index of the wanted text. For example:

```
// Find all texts
$texts = $html->find('div#content text');

foreach ($texts as $key => $txt) {
    // Display text and the parent's tag name
    echo "<br/>TEXT $key is ", $txt->plaintext, " -- in TAG ", $txt->parent()->tag ;
}
```

You'll find that you should use index `4` instead of `0`:

```
$scrape->find("div#content text",4);
```

And if your text doesnt have always the same index but you know for example that it follows the `h3` heading, then you could use something like:

```
foreach ($texts as $key => $txt) {
    // Locate the h3 heading
    if ($txt->parent()->tag == 'h3') {
        // Grab the next index content from $texts
        echo $texts[$key+1]->plaintext;
        // Stop
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Enissay, once I worked out what your code was doing, it all made sense.  Works perfectly and is a great way to solve the issue.  Many thanks.

Comment: Actually, this works perfectly on the listing page that I've been testing, however every listing page on the website has the text I want allocated to a different 'text number'.  It varies from page to page.  Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Thanks Enissay, I have just tried this again and managed to get some of the text displayed, however only the first sentence (which is repeated about 50 times).   Each sentence in the paragraph of text I need is separated by <br> tags so the [$key+1] code is only returning the first sentence, a [$key+3] code is only returning the second sentence, etc ...  Any ideas ?

Comment: hmm, a fast idea would be to remove all the `br`'s: `foreach ( $scrape->find("br") as $br ) { $br->outertext = ""; }`. Then apply your code... Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to get this to work as it seems to clash with the rest of the code on the page.   I'll attempt to revisit it again soon and hopefully will find a solution.  Thanks again.