# How to find the text contents between two siblings using simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I want to find the text contents between two tags .. My html is as follows

```
<h2>Class</h2>
   Diamond House
<h2>Contact Person</h2>
   Mr. Jennifer Therese
<h2>Address</h2>
```

I want to get the text say `Diamond House`.. I have already looped this `h2`

```
foreach($new_html->find('div[class=page-content] h2') as $element2)
{
    echo $heading = $element2->innertext;
    echo ' '.$content = $element2->find('',0)->next_sibling();
    exit;
}
```

Please advice me how to do this

Comment: It can't be done as worded with simple html dom.

Comment: [`This`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25562553/1519058) should help (check the last part of the answer)